# Accessing Resources at Runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have an XML file included as part of my Silverlight 4.0 project that I'd like to access at runtime. I have the file saved in a directory named Resources with the Build Action set to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory set to "Do not copy". If I decompress the XAP file, I see the XML file in the location I expect it to be, but I'm not sure how to reference it from code. I currently have the following:

```
Stream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(@"/AssemblyName;component/Resources/MyFile.xml")
```

Unfortunately, stream is null after running the code above. In addition to the path mentioned above, I've tried "/Resources/MyFile.xml", "/MyFile.xml" and "MyFile.xml", but they all experience the same behavior.

What is the correct way to access an XML file embedded as a resource in a Silverlight application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resource with build action "Content" just gets embedded into the xap file, with the same relative directory structure as the application. It does not get embedded as a resource in the assembly.

When set to build action "Content", you should be able to just load the file using something like (or whatever suits your needs):

`XElement.Load(<relative directory>/<file>)`

The method you're using currently (using a resource stream) is for embedded resources (which have their build action set to "Resource"). And for those, although I haven't tried yet if your method works, usually you'll get the resources using

```
Application.GetResourceStream
```

Comment: I actually tried setting the build action to "Resource", but the same thing happened (stream is null after executing). XElement.Load() throws the following exception: Cannot find file '/Resources/MyFile.xml' in the application xap package.

Comment: @senfo: Remove the first forward slash (i.e.: "Resources/MyFile.xml"), and it should work (assuming "MyFile.xml" is in a subdirectory called "Resources" in the silverlight project).

Comment: @senfo: You're welcome. For what it's worth, resources in Silverlight can be a bit of a jungle...

Answer (score 1):

I have used the code snip below to get access to drawables.  Not sure it's completely relevant, but hoping this will give you a hint one way or another ...

```
Resources res = getResources();
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("groups").setIndicator("Groups", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_groups)).setContent(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned by Willem van Rumpt, "content" resources are not usual resources (they aren't stored in assembly). I've checked out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)  and could't found at all that you could reference resource, marked as "content" from other assembly.

So, you have two options:

1. Define XML as embedded resource
2. Define XML as resource

In first case stream request looks like:

```
        var a = Assembly.Load("AssemblyName");
        var s = a.GetManifestResourceStream(@"DefaultNamespace.Resources.XMLFile2.xml");
```

In second case:

```
        var a = Assembly.Load("AssemblyName");
        var rm = new ResourceManager("AssemblyName.g", a);
        using (var set = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true))
        {
            var ums = (UnmanagedMemoryStream)set.GetObject(@"Resources/XMLFile1.xml", true);
        }
```

Hope this helps.